# How to preserve line break in textarea using simple html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, textarea

My linebreak is not recognized whenever I save it.

When I use `<br />` it appears as it is included in the paragraph.

I tried ASCII code but when I save it, it is being removed.

Comment: show some that you have tried.

Comment: post the code where you used `<br/>`

Comment: wrap=hard........

Comment: I tried <br /> and an ASCII code &#013;

Comment: "When I use `<br />`" — What does this mean? When you type `<br />` into the textarea as a user of the webpage? " appears as it is included in the paragraph" — What paragraph?  "when I save it" — How do you save it? "it is being removed" — How are you determining this? You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Example: <textarea> text1 <br /> text2 </textarea> Output: text1 <br /> text2. It is not recognized. I am using an intranet site in editing this.